# Correct way to set background image URL in React JSX object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to set the background image in my style JS object. For some reason the following is not working, no image appears and no errors?

React

```
const homeStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100vh',
    backgroundImage: 'url("../../assets/images/home.png")',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    paddingTop: '160px',
    paddingLeft: '400px'
  };

 <div style={homeStyle}></div>
```

Any idea's?

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Use the developer tools in your browser. Use the element inspector to look at the CSS applied to the element. Do you see the properties? So they have the values you expect? Are any of them having the effect you expect? (e.g. the dimensions should show up in the tool). Use the Network tab. Do you see the HTTP request for the image file? Does it get the response you expect? With the right data, content-type, and status code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to import the image with

```js
import Background from '../../assets/images/home.png';
```

and replace the backgroundImage property with

```js
backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
```